# How do I make people I follow on Instagram private

Tags: privacy, follow, instagram

I just wondered if there was a way of making the people that I follow on Instagram private, it's just that some of the people that I follow have their 'following' list set as what appears to be private, when you click on 'following' the message 'no users found' appears 
Of anyone knows why this is or how I can apply to my account I'd be greatful.